# Python - How to raise a value error of multiple items in list

Tags: python, binary

If I have a list of items which is going to be in the end a binary number, how do I get the program to say value error (or something similar) when the list is longer than 8 numbers and not a 1 or a 0???

i.e [1,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,1]
This should give an error saying the list has an non 1 or 0 number and its more that 8 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.  Whether it's as clean as you want is up to you:

```
if len(l1) != 8 or len([n for n in l1 if n not in (1, 0)]) != 0:
  raise ValueError('Invalid entries or incorrect length')
```

Comment: `n` is just the name given to each item as it grabs it from the list. Also, try `any(n for n in l1 if n not in (1, 0))` instead of `len([n for n in l1 if n not in (1, 0)]) != 0`, it does exactly the same thing but faster and with less memory.

Comment: @tyim - That's just List Comprehension syntax.  `n` could be any variable name you wanted to use.  It's a placeholder for the individual values of the initial list so that we can check them in turn.

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(my_list) > 8 or any((x is not 0) and (x is not 1) for x in my_list):
    raise ValueError
```

Doesn't create any intermediate list and stops on the first bad number (as well as working for numbers shorter than eight digits).

If you **want** to accept values like `True` for `1` or `False` for `0`,

```
if len(my_list) > 8 or any(x in (0, 1) for x in my_list):
    raise ValueError
```

works the same way.

Comment: `x not in (0, 1)` is more pythonic (actually it makes the condition look almost like plain english :) )

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not sure it's more Pythonic, and it's wrong -- `False in (0, 1)` is `True`.

Comment: damn.. (blabla characters to go)

Comment: That's an interesting definition of "wrong", since `int(False) == 0`, also `x is not 0` only happens to work in standard Python, because the values 1 and 0 are so common that the interpreter maps them all to a single instance. `is` checks for identity, not equality.

Comment: I know all of that, but if I had a list of what were supposed to be either `1`s or `0`s, and I wanted to filter out all other values, that would include `True` and `False`. For other versions of Python which might not intern small integers (which he would have mentioned were he using one) you'd have to do `(x == 0) and type(x) is int` or something similar.

Comment: `True` and `False` deliberately resolve to integers, so you are only removing a language feature by preventing them from being used that way.

Comment: I'm shortcutting checking both type and equivalence -- I suppose you could say you're removing a language feature whenever you check type in Python because it prevents duck typing, but in some situations it's what you want. I wouldn't want `0.0` to be valid either -- it would also signify a mistake somewhere in my code, just as `False` or `2` would.

Comment: Unless you were using a bit mask to store `True`/`False` values, or rounding values randomly selected from a uniform 0-1 distribution, in which case using the fact that `False` and `0.0` both resolve to `0` sounds like a pretty good idea.

Comment: Except this is obviously not what the person asking the question is doing. If you were doing any of those things, you wouldn't need to check if your generated numbers were binary every time -- you'd write a correct conversion and check it or write tests. If, on the other hand, you're just learning to program, my method won't hide any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
def typeoferror(mybytes):
    return [
        len(mybytes) != 8,
        any(True for i in mybytes if i not in [0,1])
    ]
```

and then use it for tests:

```
if typeoferror(mybytes)[0] and typeoferror(mybytes)[1]:
    raise ValueError('Is not 8-items long and has elements other than 0 or 1')
elif typeoferror(mybytes)[0]:
    raise ValueError('Is not 8-items long')
elif typeoferror(mybytes)[1]:
    raise ValueError('Has elements other than 0 or 1')
```

The same code in action: http://codepad.org/tih9ewKq

Of course you can cache result of the `typeoferror()` function to gain some performance.

Is this what you asked for?

**EDIT:**

Solution made more efficient, as suggested by [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf).

Comment: If you're going to have multiple cases they should be inside the function, not outside of it, and I can't believe you came up with a version that was less performant than @g.d.d.c -- you de-optimized an unoptimized solution. Also, he said "when the list is __longer__ than 8 numbers" not "when the list is longer or shorter than 8 numbers".

Comment: Actually, his is the only answer that fully answers the question: "This should give an error saying the list has an non 1 or 0 number and its more that 8 numbers."

Comment: @agf You may be partially right. Still, my solution is closer to answering the question than your answer, I believe. As Brent mentioned: "_error saying the list has an non 1 or 0 number **and** its more that 8 numbers_", thus the multiple cases. The function is only to determine the error, not to throw one. It is only as a proof of concept (if you could call some simple code that way).

Comment: It's just the error condition -- your error condition is "not 8 items long" rather than "longer than 8 numbers".